# how to use scp inside ssh in a shell script

Tags: scp

I have a server ServerA ( user1 as userid) .I want to connect to same server ServerA with userid as user2 and then do scp to get files from other server and keep in ServerA server(userid as user2).

Could anyone please help me out asap.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to do the scp as user1, then chown the files to user2? If you need to store them in a place accessible only to user2 you could su to user2 and move them.

Comment: no help so far. not able to change the ownership of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Say you're on hostC (client) and you want to copy files from userX@hostA to userY@hostB.

You can issue an scp command on hostC:

```sh
scp userX@hostA:file-to-copy userY@hostB:destination-folder/
```

However, you need to authenticate. If you have an ssh key set up for userX@hostA key authentication will work fine.

However `scp` will invoke `ssh` with options to either disable agent forwarding or clear forwarding keys, so that even if you have a key for userY@hostB it won't be available to hostB and you'll be prompted for a password.

One solution to this is to pass a `-S <ssh-command>` to the invocation of `scp` on `hostC` with a wrapper script to strip out the options that prevent agent forwarding, perhaps having to explicitly enable it.

e.g.

`ssh-wrapper.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, os

def is_exe(fpath):
  return os.path.exists(fpath) and os.access(fpath, os.X_OK)

def which(program):
  fpath, fname = os.path.split(program)
  if fpath:
    if is_exe(program):
      return program
  else:
    for path in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep):
      exe_file = os.path.join(path, program)
      if is_exe(exe_file):
        return exe_file
  return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
  ssh = which('ssh')
  assert ssh is not None
  args = [ssh] + sys.argv[1:]
  for x in ('-a','-oClearAllForwardings yes'):
    if x in args:
      args.remove(x)
  if '-oForwardAgent yes' not in args:
    args.insert(1,'-oForwardAgent yes')
  os.execl(ssh,*args)
```

Invoking `scp`:

```sh
scp -S ssh-wrapper.py userX@hostA:file-to-copy userY@hostB:destination-folder/
```

Comment: As `scp` explicitly prevents you from doing this, I assume it's of questionable security. You'd have to completely trust `userA` not to abuse your credentials.

Comment: Thank you Matt for your quick response but Hope you didn't get my question . I want my shell script which is present in HostC server will login to same server HostC but with different userid (user2) and from there it will copy a file from another server HostB and keep the file there (server HostC). The owner of the file will be userid(user2).

Comment: In which case: `scp -S ssh-wrapper.py userX@HostB:file-to-copy user2@HostC:destination-folder/`